# Randomize an array using useEffect in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, random, next.js, use-effect, server-side-rendering

I'd like to randomize an array everytime the page is loaded. I'm using Nextjs and the first issue is that client and server don't match, so I've been advised I need to put the randomize code inside a useEffect hook, but I'm obviously doing it wrong... i'd like some help to understand how to fix my code please.

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  useEffect(()=>{
    let randomizeArray = [...array].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());

    let selectedRandomArray = randomizeArray.slice(0, 3);
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      {selectedRandomArray.map((s, id) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <h2>{s.name}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the example in Codesandbox without the useEffect. It works but I´m getting unmatched client/server in console
https://codesandbox.io/s/shuffle-array-and-return-random-values-in-nextjs-veqy3w?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to moving the randomise logic inside a `useEffect`, you have to create a state variable (`randomArray`) and store the randomised array into it (`setRandomArray()`). This will trigger a component re-render and display the updated UI.

```js
const array = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 3 }, { name: 4 }, { name: 5 }];

export default function IndexPage() {
    const [randomArray, setRandomArray] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const randomizeArray = [...array].sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
        setRandomArray(randomizeArray.slice(0, 3));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {randomArray.map((s, id) => (
                <div key={id}>
                    <h2>{s.name}</h2>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```